# How to delete dll file after its unload

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to delete DLL when it's get unloaded from program (like when FreeLibrary is called or program is closing). How do I do that?

Comment: You should be able to delete it immediately after it has been *loaded*. Users never really "delete" files, they only unlink them. Deletion is done by the OS when there are no further open handles. (But I'm not 100% sure that that's accurate on Windows; double-check.)

Comment: @Ron I know how to do it. I cannot delete dll when it's injected in memory, so I want to delete it when its unloaded

Comment: You could poll `GetModuleHandle`. Otherwise if you want a notification, AFAIK you'll have to debug the process and wait for the  `UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` for the DLL. You'd need an external debugger process that sets an event since a program can't debug itself.

Comment: @KerrekSB - technically that could work on windows. The core usermode API for opening files `CreateFile` supports a flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` that will unlink the file and delete it when all handles are closed. However to actually use it, all callers must use the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` sharing mode flag and in practice that sharing flag is not specified a lot. I'm pretty sure the OS dll loader doesn't use it.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: Thanks - I forgot that Windows locks files typically.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the task is pretty simple - call DeleteFile; if it fails (i.e. the dll is still locked), then call MoveFileEx with MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag. However if the dll resides somewhere in 'Program Files', then the program won't be able to delete it without raising privileges. That is, the user will have to rerun the program 'as administrator' and to confirm privilege elevation.

Comment: `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` can only be used by an administrator or SYSTEM. Other users do not have the right to modify the Session Manager's "FileRenameOperations" key.